# What is the difference between conformal and fractal?

Tags: geometry

In physics, the word "conformal" typically denotes scale-invariance.

The word "fractal" implies self-similarity.

I wonder what is the exact difference between these two seemingly synonymous words.

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: [Fractals are tipically not self similar](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gB9n2gHsHN4)

Comment: These are not even apples and oranges,  more like 'apples' and 'shopping.'